# Forming a #include file name from a number

Tags: c++, macros, include

Given a numeric macro as input via the C++ compiler's `-D` option, can I form a filename for use with a `#include` statement from it? For example, currently I might have:

```
#include "data/1024_cadr.h"
```

...but I would like to form this include string through use of `-DSIZE=1024` during invocation of the compiler. I would then use this from within a script which drives the compiler, and runs some tests. I would prefer not to include all of the file names explicitly, as the scripts use the numeric value (here 1024) elsewhere.

I tried the following (and other ideas), with no luck:

```
#define str(x) #x
#include "data/"##str(SIZE)##"_cadr.h"
```

Comment: `#include MAKE_CADR(SIZE)` where `#define MAKE_CADR(x) MAKE_CADR2(x)` and `#define MAKE_CADR2(x) MAKE_CADR3(data/x##_cadr.h)` and `#define MAKE_CADR3(x) #x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by @Eljay by comment, the following will do the job:

```
#define  MAKE_CADR3(x) #x
#define  MAKE_CADR2(x) MAKE_CADR3(data/x##_cadr.h)
#define  MAKE_CADR(x)  MAKE_CADR2(x)
#include MAKE_CADR(SZ)
```